# Support authentication in FIWARE Monitoring generic enabler

Tags: fiware, fiware-monitoring

I would like to work with the FIWARE Monitoring component in order to analyse the data that I recover from my own node. But I would like to know if this component support authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIWARE Monitoring GE is currently moving towards an architecture based on OpenStack [Monasca](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Monasca). Any access through **Monasca API** to metrics, events and/or alarms stored at database requires [auth tokens](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Monasca#Keystone_Requirements) generated by Keystone service.

Comment: Where can I obtain that auth token?